# Dynamically changing container background as child is revealed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a bit of issues figuring out how I manipulate a container based on the visibility of the content.

In this case it is a slider with two slides. Given that it could have many slides with different 'colors'; and I want to change the background color of the container.

```
<div class="slider-container">

    <div class="slider-post red" aria-hidden="false">
        some content
    </div>

    <div class="slider-post green" aria-hidden="true">
        some other content
    </div>
</div>
```

The slider uses `aria-hidden` to determine whether the slide is visible or not.

So what I was thinking was:

```
if ( $('.slider-post').hasClass('red') && $('.red').attr('aria-hidden') == "false" ) {
    $('slider-container').addClass('red-container');
}
else if( $('.slider-post').hasClass('green') && $('.green').attr('aria-hidden') == "false" ) {
    $('slider-container').addClass('green-container');
}
```

But this results in the `slider-container` always being red, `red-container`.
I guess this is because as soon as the if statement evaluates as true it stops checking any further.

So how would i continuously check if the 'statements' are true or false?
Furthermore, I can see I will run into a problem removing the added classes again, considering the following example:

```
if ( $('.slider-post').hasClass('red') && $('.red').attr('aria-hidden') == "false" ) {
    $('slider-container').addClass('red-container');
    $('slider-container').removeClass('green-container');
}
```

what if there is a yellow, blue, brown container, and so on?

Comment: Why dont you exectue this if else thing in the js of the slider?

Comment: Great question. In this particular case it is a third party plugin that generates the slider. So how it is implemented is out of my reach. Also the color classes are dynamically added from the backend and are user generated. So I need to handle the situation with what I got here :(

Comment: You must be having its js right? You can read the code a bit and figure that out..

Comment: yeah. Which part are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can attach the slide change action to an event. Click on next/prev arrows for example. This way, your if statement will be checked.

If you have a lot of slides, you can get its background-color and apply this color to your container :

```
var color = $(this).css("backgroundColor");
$('slider-container').css("backgroundColor", color);
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a good idea. After more research I found out I can tap into an event that is called before the next slide.